How to resolve build wheel error while running pip install -r requirements.txt
I'm using my conda virtual environment. I tried to install same wheel version like in requirements.txt and I'm not getting any errors but when I try to install again pip install -r requirements.txt I'm getting same error. Also intalled one by one pacage from requirement.txt but after I run pip install -r requirements.txt, same error.
My error:
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-23wnlpnp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-23wnlpnp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-23wnlpnp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.



The error "uvloop does not support Windows at the moment" looks pretty clear. Use Linux. Docker or WSL2.

https://github.com/Vizonex/Winloop found in https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/536 - I am in no affiliation to uvloop or winloop and have not used either, so no guarantee that it works

@FlyingTeller I will try. Thank you.

As highlighted by @phd, you have a clear error message RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment. If you must use uvloop, you can get WSL2 which installs a Linux distribution in your Windows machine. See How to install Linux on Windows with WSL.
The second probable fix is to use winloop, which is an alternative library for uvloop on windows as commented by @FlyingTeller. Note that this package requires: Python >=3.8.0
